# Why does npm throw error when I try to install sharp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

Whenever I am trying to install sharp@0.18.2, I am encountering the following error-

[image: C++ ERRORS I GUESS?]

These are probably C++ errors thrown by node-gyp.
Following is my architectural setup -

- node v12.22.12
- MacOS 12.5.1
- npm 6.14.16
- node-gyp 9.3.0
- python 3.9.6

Answer (score 2):

That version of the module that you're attempting to use is about five years old. Is there any reason not to use the most recent version? The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp), at least for the most recent version, mention that the module supports node versions `>= 14.15.0` though, so you might want to update your node version. You can see [here](https://endoflife.date/nodejs) that node 12, your current version, is no longer being maintained.

> Most modern macOS, Windows and Linux systems running Node.js >= 14.15.0 do not require any additional install or runtime dependencies.

Comment: Actually I am dealing with a legacy project and I need to setup it on another server. So I guess I need to use node v12 only.